# ADAL for iOS exception with a different user sign-on

Tags: ios, azure, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using the ADAL iOS library for Azure authentication. However, I am having a problem if I first signed on with one account, and then sign-out and sign-in with another account. I get the following error, even though I set 'AD_PROMPT_ALWAYS'.

```
2015-08-31 12:50:39.939 PortalDev[908:174411] ADALiOS [2015-08-31 11:50:39 - xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx] ERROR: Error raised: 19. Additional Information: Domain: ADAuthenticationErrorDomain ProtocolCode:(null) Details:Different user was authenticated. Expected: 'aaa@xxx.com'; Actual: 'bbb@xxx.com'. Either the user entered credentials for different user, or cookie for different logged user is present. Consider calling acquireToken with AD_PROMPT_ALWAYS to ignore the cookie.. ErrorCode: 19.
2015-08-31 12:50:39.943 PortalDev[908:174411] ADAL Error: 19, Different user was authenticated. Expected: 'aaa@xxx.com'; Actual: 'bbb@xxx.com'. Either the user entered credentials for different user, or cookie for different logged user is present. Consider calling acquireToken with AD_PROMPT_ALWAYS to ignore the cookie. (status: 2)
```

I cleared the cache, and tried and cleared the cookies I think:

```
if (allItems.count > 0) {
            [cache removeAllWithError:&error];
            if (error) {
                CLSNSLog(@"Error clearing cache: %@", error.errorDetails);
            } else {
                CLSNSLog(@"Items removed.");
            }
        } else {
            CLSNSLog(@"Was no user cached.");
        }


        NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
        NSArray* cookies = cookieStorage.cookies;
        if (cookies.count)
        {
            for(NSHTTPCookie* cookie in cookies)
            {
                CLSNSLog(@"Deleting Auth Cookie %@.", cookie.name);
                [cookieStorage deleteCookie:cookie];
            }
            CLSNSLog(@"Auth Cookies cleared.");
        }
```

But I don't think there were any cookies to clear.
The username is pre-filled when I get the logon webpage. I thought it worked fine a few weeks/months ago, but now there seems a problem. I build the library fresh today from the latest GitHub source.

Any suggestions how I can make switching user name possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says:

> Expected: 'aaa@xxx.com'; Actual: 'bbb@xxx.com'

That indicates that a userId parameter is being passed to acquireToken.  That would cause the username field in the sign-in page to be prefilled.  However, the error is saying that when the user signed in they changed the username field to a different user.  Because you asked for a specific user but did not get a token for that user, acquireToken returns an error.  See this answer for more detail:

[ADAL iOS - Different user was authenticated. Expected userA@mydomain.com, actual userB@mydomain.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694432/adal-ios-different-user-was-authenticated-expected-useramydomain-com-actual/26727024#26727024)

Comment: Wish that I had realised that a few days ago. I did pass the username if it was known, to make logon easier the second time, but didn't realise that that was the cause of the problem. I thought it was only to pre-fill the form... Should have been a bit sharper!